# Adding to url with link

Tags: php, html

My url contains many variables that I want untouched (don't worry they aren't important).

Let's say it contained...

> ../index.php?id=5

How would I make a url that just adds

> &current=1

rather than replacing it entirely?

I'd like...

> ../index.php?id=5&current=1

rather than..

> ../index.php?current=1

I know it's a simple question but that's why I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Why even use GET variables if they're mostly static anyways?

Comment: Because the variables I'm using are static. No need to mess with session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append a parameter to a URL you can do this:

```
function addParam( $url, $param ){
    if( strrpos( $url, '?' ) === false){
        $url .= '?' . $param;
    } else {
        $url .= '&' . $param;
    }
    return $url;
}

$url = "../index.php?id=5";

$url = addParam( $url, "current=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just create your link to 'add' that parameter

`<a href="index.php?id=5&current=1">The Link</a>`

and then obviously in the **index.php** somewhere you'll look for the current variable and do what you need to:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['current']) && !empty($_GET['current]) {

        // Do stuff here for the 'current' variable
        $current = trim($_GET['current']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: That's nice but I'd like a generic way. Just a simple link with an added $_GET variable.

Comment: @Anthony What exactly do you mean generic? You need to enhance more on what you need..?

Comment: I was thinking herf+="?..." but that didn't work. How else can I do this?

Comment: You do it the way we showed you..? if you link it to `?current=1` it **will** go to `index.php?current=1`. Hence why you'd link it with what you need -----> `index.php?id=5&current=1`

Answer (score 0):

On the links that you require the $current variable, I suppose that you could just casually put it in the href attribute. For the index,php file, so something like this....

```
if(isset($_GET['current']))
{
    $current = $_GET['current'];
    //Do the rest of what you need to do with this variable
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking for. Basically, I need a way to add to the url, not make the url.

Comment: Add the URL to the href attribute? Add it where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$givenVar = "";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val){
    $givenVar .= "&".$key."=".$val;
}
$var = "&num=1";
$link = "?".$givenVar."".$var;

echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the variable to the `href`,

```
 <a href="&current=1"></a>
```

When you clink it while the address is

```
../index.php?id=5
```

trust me you then go to

```
../index.php?id=5&current=1
```

**BUT** if you click that link again, than you 'll go to

```
../index.php?id=5&current=1&current=1
```

Actually I thinks that's tricky and bad practice to just append the variable.

I suggest you to do it like:

```
<?php 
  $query = isset($_GET) ? http_build_query($_GET) . '&current=1' : 'current=1';
?>

<a href="http://url.com/?<?php echo $query; ?>">A Label</a>
```

take a look http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why in Earth you would need this, but here we are. This should do the trick.

```
$appendString = "&current=1";
$pageURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].$appendString;
```

$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] should return just the name of the requested page, with any other GET variable attached. The other string should be clear enough!